# "method stream() is undefined for the type Set<Person>"

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to run an example java program I found in the java essential trails lessons.  I want to step through it using eclipse to better understand what's going on.  The Person class is fine with no errors but the MRTest class has one error at the end, that the stream() method is undefined for the type that's calling it.  I don't know how to fix this.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;

public class MRTest {

    // The method transferElements copies elements from one collection to
    // another

    public static <T, SOURCE extends Collection<T>, DEST extends Collection<T>>
        DEST transferElements(
            SOURCE sourceCollection,
            Supplier<DEST> collectionFactory) {

            DEST result = collectionFactory.get();
            for (T t : sourceCollection) {
                result.add(t);
            }
            return result;
    }  

    public static void main(String... args) {

        List<Person> roster = Person.createRoster();        

        for (Person p : roster) {
            p.printPerson();
        }


        Person[] rosterAsArray = 
            roster.toArray(new Person[roster.size()]);

        class PersonAgeComparator
            implements Comparator<Person> {
            public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
                return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
            }
        }

        // Without method reference
        Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, new PersonAgeComparator());

        // With lambda expression
        Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray,
            (Person a, Person b) -> {
                return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
            }
        );

        // With method reference
        Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);

        // Reference to an instance method of a particular object
        class ComparisonProvider {
            public int compareByName(Person a,
                Person b) {
                return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
            }

            public int compareByAge(Person a,
                Person b) {
                return a.getBirthday().compareTo(b.getBirthday());
            }
        }
        ComparisonProvider myComparisonProvider = new ComparisonProvider();
        Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, myComparisonProvider::compareByName);

        // Reference to an instance method
        // of an arbitrary object of a particular type

        String[] stringArray = { "Barbara", "James", "Mary", "John",
            "Patricia", "Robert", "Michael", "Linda" };
        Arrays.sort(stringArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);

        Set<Person> rosterSetLambda =
            transferElements(roster, () -> { return new HashSet<>(); });

        Set<Person> rosterSet = transferElements(
            roster, HashSet::new);
        System.out.println("Printing rosterSet:");
        rosterSet.stream().forEach(p -> p.printPerson()); // This is the line that is the problem.
    }
}
```

Comment: What Java compiler is your Eclipse using?

Comment: What version of the Java JDK do you have? Streams were added in 8, so you might have an older version.

Comment: eclipse luna 4.4, JRE8 and java compliance level 1.8

Comment: Not JRE, which compiler compliance level?

Comment: refresh, rebuild after update

Comment: I just refreshed and cleaned.  I noticed "Build Automatically" was checked as well.  I'm still getting this error.

Comment: That was it!  The java order/export had 1.7 checked and it was above 1.8.  I unchecked 1.7, checked 1.8 and moved it up and it fixed it.  Thanks Jigar!

Comment: You are welcome, (added as answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was you had 1.7 SE library in your classpath, Changing it to 1.8 fixed it

<sub>See detail in question comments section</sub>